# Figures causing unacceptable spacing between enumerated elements

Tags: floats, positioning

I have an issue where, due to figure placement, spacing between items in an `enumerate` environment is being increased to an unacceptable amount.

What is standard practice for fixing this type of issue?

I've tried providing the command `\raggedbottom`, and I've tried adjusting the positioning using the optional argument for a figure enrivonment, but neither of these fixed the issue.

I realise this is quite a generic question, so please let me know if more detail is required.

**Edit**

I've managed to resolve this issue by simply rephrasing my sentences. This isn't an ideal solution, but it has done the job.

Comment: Are you perhaps using `[H]`?

Comment: @egreg No, I've omitted the optional argument because no combination seemed to produce satisfactory results.

Comment: figures should normally float and not affect the spacing at their original place at all (but their are situations where there can be an affect on the original spacing but can usually be avoided,

Comment: following from your edit I would guess that the issue is not the float but you are using `\flushbottom` and the following page has a large unbreakable object so the page is underfull  and stretched vertically.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, yes. I have a large ```align``` environment on the next page.

Comment: well there you go then `\allowdisplaybreaks` (or `\raggedbottom`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Problem solved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as clarified by comments) is unrelated to the floating figure.

If you use a class that defaults to `\flushbottom` (or you specify that explicitly) then if a page is underfull it has to be stretched to reach the bottom. If you have a large unbreakable math display on the following page the page may be forced to be underfull in this way.

You can use `\allowdisplaybreaks` so that the display can split over the page break, or you can use `\raggedbottom` so the page with the list is still short but the extra space is at the bottom rather than between each item